# CSS Flexbox - Set item width to largest one

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list of items which should display in a row. I dynamically add some items with different text lengths to the list. Is it possible to align the items on the left side and set the width of each item to the width of the largest one?

I added an image to clarify it :

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item with long text added dynamically</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: If nothing restricts the width of the largest item, what is supposed to trigger the new line in the third element ?

Comment: `set the width of each item to the width of the largest one`? Who sets `the width of the largest one` then? I guess the OP wants to set the width equally and occupy the whole containing block.

Comment: @J.Joe Look at the picture: the blocks don't occupy the whole container. That's the only difficulty here.

Comment: I'd put the same flex on all children, and add a ::after to fill the space when necessary

Answer (score 3):

To get the width of your element using javascript :

```
document.getElementById('yourID').clientWidth
```

Then you can use this value to adjust your other items

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible with just the flex-box model and no javascript. A solution (depending on your real use case) would be to use `display: table` :

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  list-style-type: none;
  table-layout: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
ul::before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  content: " ";
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  bottom:0;
  width: 500px;
  background: #999;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 33%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li+li {
    border-left: 10px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item with long text</li>
</ul>
```

Note that it's still tricky but I don't see any better css based solution.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;`? I guess that is not what the OP want.

Comment: @J.Joe There's nothing telling how the third block should be sized if you can add new lines. There's a missing requirement here. But I think I'll vote to close the question, it hasn't be though enough.